# Derivation for moment of inertia of the shell

Tags: classical-mechanics, moment-of-inertia

I'm trying to find the moment of inertia of a shell(basically a sphere where all the mass is concentrated on the surface of the sphere) using triple integration. 
The equation of the sphere 
$x^2 +y^2 +z^2 = r^2$ .
We know that
 $$
I_z=\int\int\int (x^2 + y^2) dm \\
=\int\int\int (x^2 +y^2) \rho(x,y,z) dV \\
$$
Where $\rho$ is the uniform density of the sphere.
Changing them into spherical coordinates. We get,
$$
(x^2 +y^2) = r^2 \sin^2{\phi}
$$
And
$$
dV = r^2 \sin {\phi} dr d\theta d\phi
$$
Thus we get
$$
I_z = \int\int\int\rho r^4 \sin^3{\phi} dr d\theta d\phi
$$
Therefore by solving the above integration give the solution. But my question is what is the limit of $r$ because we can't integrate it from $0$ to $r$ since the mass is concentrated on the surface of the sphere only so what will be the limit of integration for $r$ ?

Comment: $r$ will be a constant. No integration over $r$.

Comment: So I have to use double integral instead of triple integral. Thank you  @FellowTraveller

Comment: Yes. Equivalently you can use a triple integral with a $\delta(r-r’)dr’$

Comment: Can you evaluate it @FellowTraveller because I'm not getting $\frac{2}{3} M r^2 $

Comment: What are your limits for $\theta$ and $\phi$?

Comment: And what do you have for $M$?

Comment: @FellowTraveller My limits are $0\leq  \theta \leq \pi $ and $0\leq \phi \leq 2\pi$

Comment: @G.Smith the dimension for Moment of inertia is $kg.m^2$ and $M$ is the total mass of the sphere

Comment: I meant $M$ in terms of $\rho$.

Comment: Given your limits for the angles, you have $\phi$ and $\theta$ reversed in your integral. $\theta$ is the “polar” angle from the $z$-axis. Recheck your $x^2+y^2$ and your $dV$.